# copy validation when form control order is changed for FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formarray, form-control

I am trying to apply validation when component is dragged and dropped using angular-material drag and drop.

Below is code of drag and drop method the form control structure:

```
dropComponent(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

   // Save values at previous index
   const tempControl = Object.assign({}, (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.previousIndex).value);

   // Change order
   (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.previousIndex).setValue(
         (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.currentIndex).value
   );
   // Clear validation
   (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.previousIndex).clearValidators();
   // Update validators according to key
   (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.previousIndex).controls.data.setValidators(
      this.getSocialValidators('key')
   ));


   (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.currentIndex).setValue(tempControl);

   (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.currentIndex).clearValidators();
   (this.form.controls.socialMedia as FormArray).at(event.currentIndex).controls.data.setValidators(
       this.getSocialValidators(tempControl.key)
   );
}
```

In the above code : swapping of formControl on the basis of index is provided.
Problem is using direct method of cdkDragDrop was that it was only shifting the values not control.

In the above method, Validation is not getting swapped.

Comment: Even I am stuck with this kind of problem

Comment: Try to call `this.form.updateValueAndValidity()` method after `clearValidators()` and `setValidators()` method.

Comment: I have no idea you want, but I'm sure that to clear and setValidators is not a good solution. Sure you can improve your validator. A validator belong to a formControl or to a FormArray/FormGroup, I'm almost sure that drag and drop -change position in the doom- don't affect the controls